# Creating Map using put() method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a dictionnary in a `<K, List<V>>` format.

```
private static Map<String, Collection<String>> dict = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
```

Using `new HashMap<>();` or `new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();` throws incompatible data types error

I need a dictionary similar to the one below.

```
a: apple, ajar, axe, azure
b: ball, bat, box
d: dam, door, dish, drown, deer, dare
u: urn, umbrella
y: yolk
```

To do this, I worte below code. put() returns incompatible paramters compilation error. What is the right way to use put() for this example?

```
dict.put("a", "apple");
dict.put("a", "ajar");
.
.
.
dict.put("u", "umbrella");
dict.put("y", "yolk");
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to place a List as the value to the map, for example:

```
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("apple", "ajar", "axe", "azure");
dict.put("a", listA);
```

Alternatively, you can use [guava Multimap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) which allows more than one value to be mapped to a given key.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to put an arrayList in the value as your Map declaration is `Map<String, Collection<String>>` so it cannot take `Map<String, String>`.

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add("apple");
 dict.put("a",list );
```

As per java 7 you can do it using diamond operator so you can create a map as,

```
List<String, List<String>> = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: There's really no reason for the verboseness, as Java 7 allows for `...= new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @SteveP. , I miss this everytime :( . While preparing for scjp 6, I had burnt down the syntax as it wasn't allowed till java 6. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would first change the type of the dictionary to

```
private static Map<Character, ArrayList<String>> dict = new HashMap<>();
```

It'll allow easier putting of array lists as generics are not covariant.

For each letter, create:

```
ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList<>();
```

and `put()` it to dict with

```
dict.put(myList);
```

Then you can add words with:

```
dict.get(letter).put(word);
```

Comment: There's really no reason for the verboseness, as Java 7 allows for `...= new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @SteveP. I just copy-pasted OP's line with changes. I'll edit it now

Comment: To person who edited my post with "Character", the OP is using a string.

Comment: @SteveP. No, I put it through but wanted to notify the OP as well. A post author can automatically approve an edit.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this;

```
    List al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("apple");
    al.add("ajar");

    HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    hm.put("a", al);

    System.out.println(hm.get("a"));
```

This is because, when you use;

```
private static Map<String, Collection<String>>
```

You **need a Collection** like a List. **DoNOT** insert **Objects as Strings**

Answer (score 1):

You can only follow the definition you have done :
`Map<String, Collection<String>>` implies you use dict.put(a,b) with a being a String and b a `Collection`.

You're trying to put a String as a value that's your problem.
You may want to do something like that :

```
Collection col = dict.get("a");
if (col == null) {
  col = new ArrayList();
}
col.add("apple");
dict.put("a",col);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exact need is [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) feature of apache-commons

```
MultiMap dict = new MultiHashMap();
dict.put("a", "apple");
dict.put("a", "ajar");
.
.
.
dict.put("u", "umbrella");
dict.put("y", "yolk");
```